# Grey screen appears with VNCviewer

Tags: linux, debian, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc

I'm having some trouble with VNCviewer as I alwayse get a grey screen when connecting, perhaps one of this files are configured incorrectly:

[image: Xvnc-session]

[image: Xstartup]

for my /etc/vnc/xstartup file I tried adding [this](http://onkea.com/ubuntu-vnc-grey-screen/) at first and even using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session) script. no success with neither of them.

About the logs, im typing `tightvncserver` and getting this:
[image: tightvncserver]

When trying `vncserver` , getting this:
[image]

My machine is raspberry pi 3 ,Debian, Kali Linux.

Comment: Is computer you trying to see over VNC is running desktop during attempt? It could be also an issue if desktop requiring encrypted connections. Try install: `apt-get install dconf-tools` and disable "require encryption" in `dconf-editor`. Uncheck also via `dconf` desktop/gnome/remote-access/enabled`. Let me know if it works

Comment: I dont have remote-access option, my dconf-editor has **apps** **ca** **desktop** **org** **system**, when going into desktop/gnome I only have **crypto** , and yes my machine that is running VNC server is running desktop(debian), I have it connected through a screen with HDMI cable while im trying to connect it with VNCviewer , from my windows 10 to kali linux machine.

Comment: Try to disable crypto

Comment: ok going into **crypto** there are **cache** and **pgp** , crypto/pgp has **encrypt-to-self** Boolean file, and its state is "encrypting the default key" is that it? beacuse nothing else seems to encrypt or encode anything, I can disable it.

Comment: Disable cache only,  also add to `~/.vnc/xstartup` `unset SESSION MANAGER;
 exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` and make sure it has executable permissions set

Comment: About disabling cache, I dont see the option to do so, how would you do it?
I have **gpg-cache-method** and **gpg-cache-ttl** none of which seems to disable anything..

Comment: Try first xstartup hack. I made typo previously,  it should be `unset SESSION_MANAGER; exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` and restart vncserver

Comment: Did that, no effect.

Comment: VNC on linux is always headache :( May I offer you another solution? install `xrdp` package and connect to server using `rdesktop` on Kali or use standard remote desktop connections from any Windows

Comment: I agree it is a headache, im going to install raspbian-jessie on my raspbien hoping that will solve it.. I will update if that has any interest to you.

Comment: Yes, sure, update with results. I actually never had a problem with `xrdp`, it always works on all flavor of nix without shaman's magics. If you need to secure connection to RDP, you may use reversed SSH port for that